# Event mouse click in visual python

Tags: python, python-3.x, python-3.6, vpython

This is a simple code from "vpython.org" tutorial:

```
from vpython import *
scene = canvas(title='Rubic solver!',
     width=800, height=600,
     center=vector(5,0,0), background=color.white,userzoom=0,userspin=0,userpan=0)
box()
while True: 
    ev = scene.waitfor('mousedown mouseup')
    print(ev)
    if ev.event == 'mousedown':
        print('You pressed the mouse button')
    else:
        print('You released the mouse button')
    print(ev.pos) # the position of the mouse
```

and when I print "ev" the output is None and then there is an error:

```
    if ev.event == 'mousedown':
AttributeError: 'NoneType' object has no attribute 'event'
```

note: I'm using Vpython7 and Python3.6 .

Comment: Why does `scene.waitfor` return `None`?

Comment: That's my question!

Comment: ... except you didn't ask *any* question. What does the documentation say?

Comment: This code is absolutely from the documentation so it says it mustn't return None.

Comment: http://www.glowscript.org/docs/VPythonDocs/mouse.html     .this is the documentation

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This bug has been fixed in VPython 7. The example you posted works.

For VPython questions it's better to post to the VPython forum, where there are many more VPython users who will see your question than if you post to stackoverflow:

https://groups.google.com/forum/?fromgroups&hl=en#!forum/vpython-users

Comment: From vpython.org: There will be frequent updates to this module. You can get the latest version this way: 
pip install vpython --upgrade

      Or if using Anaconda, conda update -c vpython vpython